# Remove a type from RuntimeTypeModel

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

I have trouble configuring protobuf-net (de)serialization. I have this model with an abstract class `A` being the parent of an undetermined number of child classes - let's call one of these types `B`. `A` and `B` are in different assemblies.  `A` is in a library and cannot be modified for each type that uses it.
To handle that, `A` has a static constructor that looks in all AppDomain assemblies for types that inherit from it; and add these types as subtypes.

The problem is that in some cases, the `AddSubType` method throws an InvalidOperationException:

```
The type cannot be changed once a serializer has been generated...
```

Upon inspection, `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.GetTypes()` contains type `B` before the call to `AddSubType`, which I believe is the issue.

So I guess I have 3 solutions:

- Remove `B` from the configured types before adding it as a subtype. **Is that possible?**
- Executing this logic before protobuf does its magic. I wouldn't even know how to do that. Is there an AppDomain load event of some kind?
- Remove `ProtoContract` from `B` and configure it entirely at runtime when adding the subtype. Seems like reimplementing protobuf-net own's logic to do the same thing.

Do you have any suggestion?

---

**Edit: How to use PrepareSerializer?**

As pointed out, I understand `Serializer.PrepareSerializer()` is the key. However there's no explanation of its usage on SO or anywhere else for what I've found. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the method will detect that `B` inherits from `A` and automatically add it as subtype?
I've tried using it on the parent and derived types, at various points in the code, to no avail.

Comment: do a google search on the following `C# PrepareSerializer method`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Protobuf.net "The type cannot be changed once a serializer has been generated"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006296/protobuf-net-the-type-cannot-be-changed-once-a-serializer-has-been-generated)